# Laravel Select Name and id of Model and use in SelectBox

Tags: forms, laravel, drop-down-menu

This is my current Function in my Controller:

```
public function addProduct()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('admin.products.add')->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

I want to only select the columns "name" and "id" from the Category Model and assign them to the selectbox in my view like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="ID">NAME</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this using the `Form`-Facade?

Comment: The problem was that `$categories` was already used on that view. I therefore only had to change the variable name. Thanks to @Filip Koblański

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try with `pluck` method from the laravel `Collection`:

```
$categories = Category::all()->pluck('name', 'id');
```

and then in the view:

```
{!! Form::select('name', $categories) !!}
```

Comment: Hm, $categories returns exactly what i want (checked with `dd()` and it returned `0 => 'Category 1'` but I get `trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: But where you get this exception?

Comment: in my view where i am using `{!! Form::select('name', $categories) !!}`

Comment: are you using: `Form::model` for creating `<form>` tag?

Comment: I'm using `Form:open` as usual

Comment: you can try with (but I don't think that it helps): `{!! Form::select('name', $categories->toArray()) !!}`

Comment: No luck sadly. `Call to a member function toArray() on array`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123862/discussion-between-scarwolf-and-filip-koblanski).

Comment: In the case of the user also use `orderBy` clause with the model. This piece of code will also do the magic.

`$categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()->pluck('name', 'id');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this generate all category

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
  @foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
  @endforeach                 
</select>
```

And if you want to set particular category selected then do this

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
  @foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}" <?php if($hotel->category_id == $category->id) { echo "selected";}?>>{{ $category->name }}</option>
  @endforeach                 
</select>
```

Comment: This works using `Category:all()` but when I use `Category::all()->pluck('id', 'name');` I get a `trying to get property of non-object` error. Do you by any chance know why? id and name are column names of my corresponding `Category`-Model Database

Comment: Do like this   $categories = Category::select('id', 'name')->get();

Comment: Pluck return array of object and all returns array of object of array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach here`

In your blade view.

```
<select name = "category[]">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
       <option value = "{{$category->id}}">{{$category->youValueHere}}></option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I'd prefer the Form Facade if possible

Comment: Why don't you try this first. If it works convert it into Facade Form.

Answer (score 0):

> Lists was deprecated in L5.2 and removed on L5.3

Try this, simple & neat.

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');

{!! Form::select('categories[]', $categories, null, [ 
        'class' => 'form-control', 'multiple'
]) !!}
```

Comment: Could it be possible that `lists()` doesn't work on Models? `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()`

Comment: `lists` was deprecated in L5.2 and removed on L5.3